# Define unique relationships in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have this simplified scenario:

```
asset device identified by deviceID
{
    o String deviceID
    o Data reading
}

concept Data identified by readingID
{
    o String ReadingID
    o Double Lng
    o Double Lat
}
```

Is it possible to avoid that different devices have the same reading associated, like a unique relationship? An example:

deviceID = 1111 --> readingID = aaaa

deviceID = 2222 --> readingID = aaaa

I am trying to avoid this situation. I tryied to use a relationship using:

```
asset device identified by deviceID
{
    o String deviceID
    --> Data reading
}
```

taking Data as an Asset, but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly your model is:

```
asset device identified by deviceID
{
    o String deviceID
    o Data reading
}

concept Data 
{
    o String readingID
    o Double Lng
    o Double Lat
}
```

secondly, relationships in Composer are not used to 'enforce' uniqueness a la RDBMS (as it doesn't use an RDBMS it uses a key/value store).

The simplest way to check if your device asset tries to use a readingID (stored in a concept, stashed in an asset in the asset registry) that's already associated with an asset is to run a query on the registry and use a true or false in your transaction code. Unless you stored the already used IDs elsewhere as a registry, but adds more maintenance etc.